# Is there any way that i can host my django project along site cgi mode site (bugzilla)

Tags: python, apache, cgi, django-wsgi

I'm trying to host bugzilla on apache2 server where I have hosted my django project previously. I want to access both websites as subdomains
is there any way that I can do it

my config files are :

000-default.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName health-diagnosis.com
        ServerAlias health-diagnosis.com
        ServerAdmin ladbhupesh1369@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        Alias /static /var/www/html/webproject/static
    <Directory /var/www/html/webproject/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/html/webproject/webproject> 
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
    WSGIDaemonProcess webproject python-path=/var/www/html/webproject python-home=/var/www/html/webproject/myvenv
    WSGIProcessGroup webproject
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/webproject/webproject/wsgi.py
    ErrorLog /var/www/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/logs/custom.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

bugzilla.conf :

```
ServerName localhost
<Directory /var/www/html/bugzilla>
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
Options +ExecCGI
DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.html
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out I have to just set different `ServerName`,`ServerAlias` different for each app